# 403 error for ajax POST request

Tags: ajax, json

I have custom plugin which receives request via admin-ajax.php

Request which works

```
curl 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ecp_track' --data-binary 'test'
```

Request which causes `403 Forbidden` error

```
curl 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ecp_track' --data-binary '{"test1": "1"}'
```

GET request works without problems.

So the only difference is POST data, where error happens only when I use valid json as payload.

Request should be json and POST because plugin uses external `.js` which can not be changed and relies on it so my question is why json causes error?

Comment: Are you sure that WP is the one who responds with 403 error and it's not caused by server (security_mod) or something like that?

Comment: GET request works fine.
POST request with simple string is passed directly into handler.
But POST request with json string causes 403 error.
@KrzysiekDróżdż

Comment: That's why I'm asking if you're sure, that WP is the one we should blame here. It looks like some mod_security (or some other server side firewall) thing to me.